# WPF Binding from strings to Canvas objects in a ResourceDictionary using Converter

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have a ResourceDictionary made up of icons/Canvas objects drawn with Paths. My ViewModel includes a string property (IconName) that contains a string matching one of the entries in the ResourceDictionary. I developed a MultiBinding (IMultiValueConverter) that takes the string, and a FrameworkElement and does a resource lookup, returning the resource matching the name. Before getting to this point, I stubbed my View explicitly with the following:

```
<Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Margin="0,0,10,0">
   <Rectangle.Fill>
       <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill" Visual="{StaticResource defalt_icon}" />
   </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

This renders correctly. However, when I switch out to the following, nothing is rendered in the Rectangle.

```
<Rectangle Width="10" Height="10" Margin="0,0,10,0">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <VisualBrush Stretch="Fill">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource IconNameConverter}">
                    <MultiBinding.Bindings>
                        <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource AncestorType=FrameworkElement}"/>
                        <Binding Path="IconName"/>
                    </MultiBinding.Bindings>
                </MultiBinding>
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

My converter (show below) is being called, and does find the Canvas object and returns it (viewing the object in the debugger I can see that Canvas has a Path child that has the right Data member filled in).

```
public class IconNameConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        FrameworkElement targetElement = values[0] as FrameworkElement;
        string iconName = values[1] as string;

        if (iconName == null)
            return null;

        FrameworkElement newIcon = (FrameworkElement)targetElement.TryFindResource(iconName);

        if (newIcon == null)
            newIcon = (FrameworkElement)targetElement.TryFindResource("appbar_page_question");

        return newIcon;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Any ideas why the canvas isn't showing up?